# send jquery datatables rows selected to server side c# asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datatables

```
function Delete() 
     {
         var iTable = $('#Dims').DataTable();
         var rows = iTable.rows('.selected').indexes();             
         document.getElementById('<%=hdnRows.ClientID %>') = rows;  

     }
```

I am trying to get the rows selected in the datatable and put it into a hidden field named hdnRows so I can delete the selected rows from a list I am using to populate the datatable.  I am not sure what type the rows variable is since it can contain several indexes (it must be a array).

I tried using a for loop and running through the variable rows and adding it to hdnRows in a comma delimited string.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
             document.getElementById('<%=hdnRows.ClientID %>') += rows[i] + ',';
         }
```

This didn't put anything into the hidden field either.  I even tried hard coding a number in just to see if it would work

```
document.getElementById('<%=hdnRows.ClientID %>') = '3';
```

I am executing a javascript function called delete from the onclientclick method of asp button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" OnClientClick="Delete()" Text="Del" />
```

Everything I read says this should work.  If anyone answers the question be sure to indicate the data type of var rows.

Once on the server side I just need to delete the selected rows from a

```
List<structs>
```

I am using to populate table

Answer (score 0):

I was very close.

```
document.getElementById('<%=hdnRows.ClientID %>').value = rows[0].toString();
```

The main things to remember are

1. You need the .value after you get the element(hidden field) by id.  Be sure to use small v not capital V as the latter won't work and on the server side it's capital V
2. The hidden field stores a string so be sure to ad the .toString() method if your using a number.

On a side note the rows variable is an array.